# how can i use browsersec extension in phantomjs

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

[browsersec](https://browsec.com/en/) is a vpn extension for chrome and Firefox but i like to use it for phantomjs here is my code without any extension

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
service_args=[]
service_args.append('--load-images=no')
service_args.append('--disk-cache=no')
service_args.append('--ignore-ssl-errors=true')
service_args.append('--ssl-protocol=tlsv1')
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=service_args)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
driver.quit()
```

i like know how to include addons to phantomjs so that i can include browsersec extension to it